# return focus and select text using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am validating text input on a html form, and would like to focus and select the text if it is invalid.

If my validation function looks like (just an example):

```
jQuery.fn.DateHelper = function(text){
    return this.each(function(){
    //Make sure we're dealing with text-based form fields
    if(this.type != 'text')
    return;

    // call the processNumber function when the onBlur event is fired and there is a value in the field.
    $(this).blur(function() {
        if (this.value != '')                 
            processNUmber(this);
        });

    function processNumber( txtField ) {
        if (!isNan(txtField ))  {
            alert("not a number");
            this.focus(); // this does not work.
            // how to select text?     
        }

    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function you pass the `txtField` parameter, use it instead of `this` within the `processNumber` function:

```
function processNumber( txtField ) {
    if (!isNan(txtField ))  {
        alert("not a number");
        txtField.focus();   
    }
}
```

Also you are declaring the `processNumber` function inside the `.each()` loop in the  `jQuery.fn.DateHelper` function which doesn't have to be the case, you can declare that function outside the `.each()` and it will be accessible to any element on which this plugin is run.

## UPDATE

Your code functions however there are several syntactical errors:

```
jQuery.fn.DateHelper = function(text){
    return this.each(function(){
        //Make sure we're dealing with text-based form fields
        if(this.type != 'text') return;

        // call the processNumber function when the onBlur event is fired and there is a value in the field.
        $(this).blur(function() {
            if (this.value != '') processNumber(this);//you were calling the processNUmber function, which doesn't exist
        }).focus(function () {
            this.select();
        });

        function processNumber( txtField ) {
            //isNan is broken: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN
            //also txtField is a DOM element, not a string
            txtField.value = txtField.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
            if (txtField.value.length > 0)  {
                alert("not a number");
                txtField.focus();    
            }
        }
    });//this was omitted
};
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uQ45E/6/

Comment: I made several alterations to the **UPDATE** in my answer, I'm done at this point, here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uQ45E/

Comment: Hi, I made some typos when entering my example code. I slightly modified your example http://jsfiddle.net/uQ45E/2/ and although I think the field returns the focus, it does not select the text. I have tried both IE and Firefox.

Comment: actually it returns a JS error. Focus() is null or not an object

Comment: @Scott.Thornton Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/uQ45E/6/. I added a `focus` event handler that selects the text in the input, the answer above has been updated.